# Why is this tree layout giving me an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 and trying to do a simple tree layout over some xml data.  I am getting an infinite loop in some d3 code and trying to find out why.  Here is a simplification of what I am doing and I am still seeing the infinite loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Spring Integration Inspector</title>
<script src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = parser.parseFromString("<beans><bean/><bean><beanChild/></bean></beans>", "text/xml");

var tree = d3.layout.tree().children(function(beanNode) {
    var children = beanNode.getElementsByTagName("*");
    if (children.length > 0) {
        return children;
    } else {
        return null;    
    }
});

var nodes = tree.nodes(xml),
    links = tree.links(nodes);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graph"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To reproduce, copy this code into an `index.html` file and include the d3.js library appropriately.  This will not load in a browser.  I think it has something to do with the children function.

---

EDIT:

I am stepping through the debugger in chrome and the problem is located inside of the `apportion` method.  The while loop never breaks.  More specifically, the `d3_layout_treeRight` and `d3_layout_treeLeft` methods (which I think tries to find the first child and last child respectively) are simply returning the current node when the current node is a leaf.

The value of `node._tree.thread` is the current node inside of `d3_layout_treeRight` and `d3_layout_treeLeft`. and so calls to those methods return the node passed in as an argument.

Comment: I would recommend using F12 to open a debugger (Firefox may require FireBug for f12) in your web browser and see if you can step through the script code or see an error.  Can children be null?  Or should you be returning an empty array?

Comment: Yes. I did that did a bit of debugging. I'll update the question to explain what I saw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described on the [d3-js google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/d3-js/91hh7Mz57cw), the problem is that I used `beanNode.getElementsByTagName("*")` instead of `beansNode.childNodes`.